# Ayuda para refrescar pantalla ionic framework

Tags: ionic, ionic-framework

Tengo un `Windows.Location.reloaded()` y cuando lo hace me manda a la pantalla de *login* o sea me cambia de pantalla, alguien sabe como puedo solucionarlo?
Espero me puedan ayudar. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Hola Sebastian puedes usar el siguiente método $state.reload, te dejo un ejemplo y el link donde puedes consultar más al respecto.

```
.controller('MyCachedViewCtrl', function($scope){
var initView = function(){...};
//...some stuff...

$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function(){
    initView();
});

$scope.refresh = function(){
    $state.reload(true);
};});
```

[Recargar Página en Ionic](http://blog.enriqueoriol.com/2016/01/ionic-framework-cache-y-refresco-de-vista.html)

Espero te sea te ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

lo que necesitas es recargar de nuevo el estado, una solución podría ser :

```
$window.location.reload(true);
```

Dentro de tu controlador, agregar $window.

```
function tuControlador($window){
}
```

Esto lo que hace es volver a recargar tu estado en el que te encuentras.Espero ayudarte